# How to implement pan gesture like iOS MAIL app such that only one cell is opened at a moment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have made custom buttons of deleting and other few options for cells similar to the iOS Mail App have "Delete", "Archive", "Flag" etc.

If you have noticed if one cell is swiped open then you cannot open another after wards, If you try then previous swipe will undo 
i.e. previously opened cell will be restored to normal position.... I wish apply same technique with mine cell.

For code, I have implemented https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views this tutorial for my app. Can any one suggest how to imitate the behaviour that only open cell be swipe enable `~=` MAIL App cell swipe behavious

The approach used is NOT of table editing, the buttons are embed on cell's super view and extra swipe view is above them which is panned across!! So no delegates method of editing of anyKind are being used!

Comment: Surely you have a reference to the cell that is currently open? Why can't you just close it?

Comment: closing a current opened cell is not an issue, PROHIBITING other cells to pan across while another cell already opened is an issue here.

Comment: Have a delegate method that's called from the cell before it pans returning a Bool of whether or not it is allowed.

Comment: doing it .... have to maintain is it same cell or not that is panned TOO!! Thanks btw! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
- (nullable NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

Comment: The approach used is NOT of table editing, the buttons are embed on cell's super view and extra swipe view is above them which is panned across!! So no delegates method of editing of anyKind are being used!